# Visualizar dados de duas tabelas mySQL em uma pagina no PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde, eu tenho um sistema, aonde se faz cadastros de pacientes.

Possuo duas tabelas no meu banco, **TABLE 1 = internacoes**, **TABLE 2 = pacientes_backup**. Eu quero exibir dados das DUAS tabelas, em uma pagina (vizuinternacao.php) só em PHP.

> Há **um** campo nas duas tabelas, aonde os dados são os mesmos,
>   exemplo:
>
> campo `nome` da **TABLE 1** = (mateus silva oliveira)
>
> campo `paciente` da **TABLE 2** = (mateus silva oliveira)

Eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma: (listagem_internacao.php)

```
<?php

$sql="";
require('conexaobd.php');

if (isset($_GET["pesquisa"])) {
$nome = $_GET["pesquisa"];
$sql = "SELECT numero_de_processo, paciente, data_de_entrada, convenio, tipo_de_internacao, data_saida FROM internacoes WHERE paciente LIKE '%$nome%' ORDER BY paciente ASC";
}else

$sql = "SELECT internacoes.numero_de_processo, internacoes.paciente, internacoes.data_de_entrada, internacoes.convenio, internacoes.tipo_de_internacao, internacoes.data_saida, pacientes_backup.sus FROM internacoes, pacientes_backup WHERE pacientes_backup.nome = internacoes.paciente ORDER BY internacoes.paciente ASC";


$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$inc = 0;

// LAÇO DE REPETIÇÃO
while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

    echo "
       <tr> 

                <td>".$cont['paciente']."</td>   
                <td>".converte_data($cont['data_de_entrada'])."</td> 
                <td>".$cont['convenio']."</td>
                <td>".$cont['tipo_de_internacao']."</td>
                <td>".converte_data($cont['data_saida'])."</td>

                 <td> 
                 <a href='vizuinternacao.php?numero_de_processo=".$cont['numero_de_processo']." &paciente=".$cont['paciente']." &sus=".$cont['sus']." target='new_blank'>
                <span class='role orange'> 
               <i class='fa fa-eye'></i>
                </span>
                </a>
                </td>

          </tr> 
    ";
}  
?>
```

Até ai creio que está certo, quando clico em algum paciente, já aparece o campo `sus`(que é da outra tabela) exato na url.

Agora minha pagina aonde quero exibir: (vizuinternacao.php)

```
<?php 
require('conexaobd.php');

$numero_de_processo = $_GET['numero_de_processo'];
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM internacoes WHERE numero_de_processo = '$numero_de_processo' ");
while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
?>

            <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->
            <br>
                <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12"> 
                                <div id="bk">

                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="card-title">
                                           <h3><center><i style="font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;">Clínica terapêutica Jeova Rafha - <a target="_blank" href="listagem_internacao.php" style="color: red">Dados da clínica</a></i></center></h3> 
                                        </div>  

                                        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php 
$sus = $_GET['sus'];
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM pacientes_backup WHERE sus = '$sus' ");
while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
// EXIBINDO A IMAGEM
echo "<img src='".$cont['foto']."' class='alignright'/>"; }  
?>

                                          <div class="form-row">
                                             <div class="col">
                                                <label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1"><b>Paciente</b></label>
                                                <select name="paciente" disabled="disabled" class="form-control custom-select">
                                                  <option value="<?php echo $cont['paciente'];?>"><?php echo $cont['paciente'];?></option>
                                                        <?php
                                                require('conexaobd.php');

                                            $sql = "SELECT nome FROM pacientes";


                                            $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

                                            $inc = 0;

                                            while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                                                echo "
                                                 <option>".$cont['nome']."</option>  
                                                ";
                                            }


                                            $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM internacoes WHERE numero_de_processo = '$numero_de_processo' ");
                                            while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {


                                            ?>   
                                                 </select>
                                             </div> 


                                              <div class="col">
                                                <label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Numero de processo</label>
                                                <input id="cc-pament" name="numero_de_processo" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="<?php echo $cont['numero_de_processo'];?>">
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <br>
                                           <div class="form-row">
                                              <div class="col">
                                                <label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Data de entrada</label>
                                                <input id="cc-pament" name="data_de_entrada" readonly="readonly" type="date" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="<?php echo $cont['data_de_entrada'];?>">
                                            </div>

// ETC, SÃO MUITOS CAMPOS... ESTOU FECHANDO CORRETAMENTE
```

Não está exibindo nenhum erro. Mas também não está mostrando o campo `foto` no caso...

**Agradeço desde já para quem tentar me ajudar, abraços!**

Answer (score 1):

Use inner join

```
SELECT internacoes.*, pacientes_backup.* FROM internacoes INNER JOIN pacientes_backup on internacoes.nome = pacientes_backup.nome WHERE ...
```

E tabém recomendo usar parenteses em subquerys para ajuda na legibilidade, e ao inves de guardar o nome nas duas tabelas, é bom você criar uma chave estrangeira na taabela internações que referencie ao id do paciente

Comment: Vou tentar e comento aqui, mas não sei não, esse `select` esta selecionando todos os campos da tabela **pacientes** e **internacoes**, porém, tem campos nas duas com o **mesmo nome**, não daria para especificar... só se eu alterasse o nome do campo no banco...

Comment: coloquei assim, mas é so você trocar o * pelo nome da coluna que quer pegar, mas se ainda sim você quiser pegar valores e por acaso tenham a coluna com o mesmo nome você ainda pode colocar tipo. internacoes.<coluna> as <nome que você quer que fique acessivel essa coluna>

Comment: Faça como o @EduardoResende lhe informou, porém recomendo que tenha na tabela "Internacoes" um campo paciente_id, onde você referenciaria o id da tabela "pacientes_backup", pode parecer impossível para você agora, mas poderá ter um problema de pacientes com nomes iguais.

Comment: Opa @EduardoResende, tentei aqui, porém não deu muito certo, estranho que nem exibe o campo da outra tabela... não sei o que fazer

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT C.nome [table 1], F.paciente AS [table 2] 
FROM table 1 AS C
INNER JOIN table AS F ON C.nome = F.paciente`

Comment: Aonde isso? em que pagina?

Comment: aonde você que mostrar os dados juntos? O certo seria você ter um campo id na sua tabela 2 de acordo com 1.